# itemClickCallBack RecyclerView on fragment to DetailActiviy with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I try to make itemClickCallback in my adapter and try to implement it in my fragment. My problem is DetailActivity can`t show when I click the card.

**CardViewMovieAdapter**

```
class CardViewMovieAdapter(private val listMovie: ArrayList<Movie>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewMovieAdapter.CardViewViewHolder>() {

.................

*intent*
                itemView.setOnClickListener {

                    val intent = Intent( context, DetailMovieActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(DetailMovieActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, movie)
                    startActivity(context,intent,Bundle())
                }
...............................

interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: Movie)
    }

}
```

**MovieFragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ........

*the itmeclikcallback*
        cardViewMovieAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : CardViewMovieAdapter.OnItemClickCallback{
            override fun onItemClicked(data: Movie) {
                showSelectedHero(data)

...............

fun showSelectedHero(movie: Movie) {
        val intent = Intent( context, DetailMovieActivity::class.java)
      intent.putExtra(DetailMovieActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, movie)
       startActivity(intent)
```

**DetailMovieActivity**

```
class DetailMovieActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{
        const val EXTRA_MOVIE = "extra_movie"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

*get data intent*

        val moviesData = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE) as Movie

        val imgPhotoMovie: ImageView = img_item_photo
        val tvMovieNane : TextView = tv_item_name
        val tvMovieDescription : TextView = tv_item_description
        val tvMovieDetail: TextView = tv_item_description2

        tvMovieNane.setText(moviesData.name)
        tvMovieDescription.setText(moviesData.description)
        tvMovieDetail.setText(moviesData.detail)

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(moviesData.photo)
            .into(imgPhotoMovie)

    }
}
```

How to fix this intent to show detailActivity with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Activity class there is no method with parameters such as `startActivity (context, intent, Bundle())`, there is method like ex. `startActivity(intent, new Bundle());`.
2. You can't call startActivity from the view, you should call it via context or activity like `context.startActivity(...)` or `activity.startActivity(...)`
   You can do it inside view like:

   `val intent = Intent(view.context, YourActivity::class.java)
    view?.context?.startActivity(intent, new Bundle())`

So just need to replace

```
startActivity (context, intent, Bundle())
```

With

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Its work! Thank you so much @Narek Hayrapetyan. After I replace that code, I found  an error in **DetailMovieActivity**
 `val moviesData = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE) as Movie` then I change the **getParceableArrayExtra** with **getParceableExtra** after do that my app run well.

Comment: @Bagus Kurnianto Good!